# Adobe AIR for iOs issue?

Tags: ios, iphone, actionscript-3, air

First off all, I am not asking for any code. I just need some help from someone whose had the same issue and knows how to solve it.

I've developed an app for iPhones using adobe air for iOS in flash cs6.

it works fine on all the iPhones (4, 5, 5s) but it doesn't install on iPhone 6 for some reason! and this stopping me from sending me app to the apple.

I have installed the latest AIR SDK which is 16.0.0.222 and I have all the relevant splash screen images for iPhone 6.

but I do not understand what is going on!

1) Could someone please let me know if I have to use different icon size for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus?

2) Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain, "doesn't install on iPhone 6"? Because even if you do not have the correct splash screen you app will still run on the iPhone 6(plus). But if the device UDID is not in the profile you will not be able to run the AdHoc/development version on the device.

Comment: @rckoenes, what I mean is that it freezes at the installation stage and it leaves a ghost APP on the iphone 6 screen. I have added 2 different UDID for 2 different iphone 6 devices to the profile but it does the same thing on both iphone 6 devices. one thing I've noticed that I haven't added the icons to support iphone 6 and 6+ to the app. but I cannot find the options for adding the icons in the icons tab in the Publish Settings! i can only see, 29x29, 57x57,114x114,512x512 EVEN though I am using the latest AIR as stated in my question! any idea how to add more icons?

Comment: I've never worked with Air, but have had some experience with app not running on new devices. Most of the time it is because there UDID is not correct or the build process is using the wrong profile. I've managed to run a iOS 7 only app in the iPhone 6. So it should not be a problem that you are missing the icon, it fail to install it is mostly due to some provisioning profile error.

Comment: @rckoenes, i think you are right.. I just looked into the mobileprovision certificate that I downloaded from the Apple development center and I cannot find the Newly added UDID numbers for iphone 6 devices in there! I can see them in my Apple developer center account under devices but when I download the XXXX.mobileprovision certificate, I cannot see them in there! any idea?

Comment: @rckoenes, OMG mate, i just found out I haven't added the UDID number when I downloaded the profile! its been added now.... thanks for pointing that out...